# Failsafe recoverPartitions

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I want to run `recoverPartitions` on tables that may or may not have partitions.

Right now I see two options, both of which feel pretty hacky:

(1) examine the `create table` statement before executing:

```
table_name = 'my_schema.my_table'
x = sql(sprintf('show create table %s', table_name))
if (grepl('PARTITIONED BY', collect(x), fixed = TRUE)) {
  recoverPartitions(table_name)
}
```

(2) `tryCatch`

```
tryCatch(recoverPartitions(table_name),
         error = function(e) {
  if (grepl('ALTER TABLE RECOVER PARTITIONS', e$message, fixed = TRUE)) 
    # expected error in case of non-partitioned table
    return(NULL)
  # else an unexpected error
  else stop(e$message, .call = FALSE)
})
```

Are these really the "correct"/"canonical" approaches to flexibly recovering partitions? I don't see anything else in the [`SparkR` documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html), and I don't see anything suggestive in a search of `[pP]artition` in the `formals` of the `Namespace` of `SparkR`.

If so, is one to preferred (e.g., efficiency) over the other?